# Facial landmarks detection using Dlib

Tags: python-2.7, dlib

How to install Dlib library and use it in python  code for facial landmarks or key points detection in an image?

How Dlib works?

Answer (score 1):

install it via pip. `pip install dlib` would do that.
And [this](http://dlib.net/face_landmark_detection.py.html) is an example of using dlib to extract face landmarks